# Split card based on overflow of data

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I wish to achieve a UI like this, where when the data overflows, it continues on the next card. Except I will have fixed height cards as compared to this below picture.

I would like to hear the possible ways to achieve this, also I'm making this in a react native project.

P.S: This is not the use case where I can do it using `numColumns` prop of FlatList.
As data here is not from 2 different data set (in Array), but from a single data set (in Array)

[image]